# SimpleDateFormat is giving wrong Date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

**I am inputting a specific date (dd/MM/yyyy) , while displaying it the Output is something else.**

```
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class InvalidUsernameException extends Exception       //Class InvalidUsernameException
{
    InvalidUsernameException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class InvalidPasswordException extends Exception      //Class InvalidPasswordException
{
    InvalidPasswordException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class InvalidDateException extends Exception      //Class InvalidPasswordException
{
    InvalidDateException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class EmailIdb1                                   //Class Email Id b1
{
    String username, password;
    int domainid;
    Date dt;

    EmailIdb1()
    {
        username = "";
        domainid = 0;
        password = "";
        dt = new Date();
    }


    EmailIdb1(String u, String pwd, int did, int d, int m, int y)
    {
        username = u;
        domainid = did;
        password = pwd;
        dt = new Date(y,m,d);       // I think There is a problem
        SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy/MM/dd"); //Or there can be a  problem

        try{
            if((username.equals("User")))
            {
                throw new InvalidUsernameException("Invalid Username");
            }
            else if((password.equals("123")))
            {
                throw new InvalidPasswordException("Invalid Password");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("\nSuccesfully Login on Date : "+formater.format(dt));

            }           
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class EmailId                                    //Class Email Id
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int d,m,y,did;
        String usn,pwd;
        EmailIdb1 eml;

        try{
            usn = args[0];
            pwd = args[1];
            did = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            d   = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
            m   = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
            y   = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);

            switch(m)
            {
                case 2: if(d==29 && y%4 == 0)
                        {
                            eml = new EmailIdb1(usn,pwd,did,d,m,y);
                        }
                        else if(d<=28 && d>=1)
                        {
                            eml = new EmailIdb1(usn,pwd,did,d,m,y);
                        }
                        else{
                            throw new InvalidDateException("Wrong Date.");
                        }
                        break;

                case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10:
                case 12: if(d>=1 && d<=31)
                         {
                            eml = new EmailIdb1(usn,pwd,did,d,m,y);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             throw new InvalidDateException("Invalid Date");
                         }
                    break;
                case 4: case 6: case 9:
                case 11: if(d>=1 && d<=30)
                         {
                             eml = new EmailIdb1(usn,pwd,did,d,m,y);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             throw new InvalidDateException("Invalid Date");
                         }
                    break;
                default : throw new InvalidDateException("Invalid Date");
            }


        }
        catch(InvalidDateException ed)
        {
            System.out.println(ed);
        }
    }
}
```

Me and my two friends have similar kind of problem. Don't know why This is Happening. My teacher also couldn't find what's the problem

The Output Should be

```
Successfully Login on Date : 1994/05/04
```

As the Input Is

```
Successfully Login on Date : 3894/06/04
```

Comment: You should not use the Date constructor with three ints, because it is deprected

Comment: What do you _do_ with the `SimpleDateFormat`? Further, empty catch blocks should never, ever, be used. P.S. the comments on your code are unhelpful at best, and at worst actually _hurt_ readability.

Comment: read the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(int, int, int): year - the year minus 1900.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yeah man..those comments are quite disturbing as well ...  ;-P

Comment: Way too much code. It is your responsibility to strip down your code to make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

```
      new Date(int year, int month, int date)
```

is deprecated - you shouldn't be using it

Second of all, according to the javadoc:

```
/**
 * Allocates a <code>Date</code> object and initializes it so that
 * it represents midnight, local time, at the beginning of the day
 * specified by the <code>year</code>, <code>month</code>, and
 * <code>date</code> arguments.
 *
 * @param   year    the year minus 1900.
 * @param   month   the month between 0-11.
 * @param   date    the day of the month between 1-31.
 * @see     java.util.Calendar
 * @deprecated As of JDK version 1.1,
 * replaced by <code>Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date)</code>
 * or <code>GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date)</code>.
 */
```

So if you pass as a year 1994, you will get Date with year "3894". If you want to get "1994", you should pass 94 as a year.
And months are represented as int from range 0-11, so if you pass 5, it is formatted as "06" in your case, because 5 represents June and not May.

Comment: Thanks, a real help...